# Is it possible to write to file without closing its reading state? PHP

Tags: php

I was curious to do a test. My question is if is it possible to open file for both reading and writing, so if I have more read-write operations to do on one file I do not need to close the reading status, read, open for write status, write and so on in a loop.

```
$filename = "test.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rwb");
fseek( $handle , 15360 );
$contents = fread($handle, 51200);

$start = microtime (true);
fseek( $handle , 1 );
fwrite ( $handle , $contents );
fclose($handle);
```

This test does not work. I expected, I will read the data and move the fseek pointer to begin of the file either 1 or 0 position and then I will write the data. But this action failed for some reason with a result 0 (int) bytes written. Hence my question is, is it possible to do it? Or I need to close file for reading first?

As a **related sub-question** - is it possible that more users can read or write from files simultaneously from different position. As this should simulate database read/write operations. You know how mysql works - more users can write same table - same file any time. I know this is not problem in C/C++ but is it possible to do it in php?

Comment: depends on the os and how you opened the file, but multiple users generally COULD open the same file, but results will be undefined depending on exactly what each of those users is doing. there's no guarantee as to order-of-operations. you sure the fread() succeeded? fwrite  would return boolean FALSE on error. returning 0 means it wrote 0 bytes, which means $contents is empty.

Comment: I can display the $contents and yea, there are data successfully read. The order of the operations can be guarantee by the users id, e.g. user with id 09 will write 1024bytes starting on 9*1024th byte, the user with id 100 will write 1024 bytes starting on 100*1024 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple file handlers on the same file. Just `fopen()` it twice, one with read only, the other with read/write.  Although I'm not sure why you'd want to do so unless you're reading and writing from two different point in the file.

```
$filename = "test.txt";
$rw_handle = fopen($filename, "c+"); //open for read/write, allow fseek
$r_handle = fopen($filename, "r");
```

If you want to have multiple processes reading and writing a file from different locations, you'll want to file lock with  `flock()`

Comment: This is good tip. I tried: `$filename = "test.txt";
$handle_rb = fopen($filename, "rb");
$handle_wb = fopen($filename, "wb");
fseek( $handle_rb , 15360 );
$contents = fread($handle_rb, 51200);
$start = microtime (true);
fseek( $handle_wb , 1 );
fwrite ( $handle_wb , $contents );
fclose($handle_rb); fclose($handle_wb);

` but my result is that the contents of the file has been deleted. Any way how to fix it? What I want to see is that the content of 50kb from the end of the file will be copied over the begin of the file and the remain of the file stays untouched. OS Win XP

Comment: You need to open the read/write to append, not how you currently have it opening.  Will update my code.

Comment: The problem with 'a+'  is: "Open for reading and writing; **place the file pointer at the end of the file**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, **writes are always appended**." So I finish with the data written on the end not on the begin. The w+ is for read/write but it truncates the file and I finish with empty file...

Comment: @John my bad , if you want to write at an arbitrary point in the file, you'll need to seek to that location and use the options 'c+' to open for read/write

Comment: @JohnBoe of course, you'll blow away anything you overwrite with "c"

Comment: For some reason I cannot open it with c+ option. and I am getting error: ` "failed to open stream: No error" - but I see now. It is supported since PHP .5.2.6 and I have 5.2.0. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @JohnBoe Ha... I literally was typing a comment "what version of php do you have", but I got rid of it before adding because I  thought "he couldn't be using php < 5.3"